# How do I sort the each line of textfile according to second element in the line and populate in ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx-2

I am trying to add text from a text file to ListView sorted in descending order by the second element one each line in the text file.

This is how my text file looks like:

```
Utkarsh 2
Stephen 1
UT 11
George 3
```

And this is what I am doing.

```
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        ObservableList<String> levels = FXCollections.observableArrayList ();
        String fileName = currGame.getName()+"_leaderboard.txt";
        try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            String[] parts;
            int  i = 0;
            while(input.hasNext()){
                String line = input.nextLine();
                parts = line.split("\\s+");
                //levels.add(line);
                namesArray[i] = parts[0];
                movesArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

                System.out.println(namesArray[i] + " " + movesArray[i]);
                i++;
            }   

            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

        Arrays.sort(movesArray);

        for(int j = movesArray.length; j > 0; j--) {
            levels.add(namesArray[j]+" "+ String.valueOf(movesArray[j]));
        }

        //System.out.println(levels);
        levelList.setItems(levels);
    }
```

It works perfectly fine if i don't split and sort, just add line to levels and set it to levelList. But when I try to split and sort, it crashes with error:

```
Oct 21, 2018 6:30:16 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.121
Oct 21, 2018 6:30:19 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.121
Oct 21, 2018 6:30:20 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.121
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/utkarshatri/UNSW/sem2-18/project/group-Optimistic-Lovers/bin/package1/leaderboard.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at package1.LeaderboardShowScreen.start(LeaderboardShowScreen.java:40)
    at package1.LeaderboardController.handleLeaderboardButton(LeaderboardController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at package1.LeaderboardShowController.initialize(LeaderboardShowController.java:46)
    ... 69 more
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which line in your function here is line 46?

Comment: @Mark namesArray[i] = parts[0]; part

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please create the smallest possible example that still shows your problem. In your case it probably does not matter that you read the input from a file, so you should show us a version without a file, for more please see [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is `namesArray` actually defined? It will throw a `NullPointerException` if it's not.

Comment: @Mark yes, namesArray is globaly defined
private int[] movesArray;
private String[] namesArray;

Comment: How did you define it?

Comment: @Mark private int[] movesArray; private String[] namesArray;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have never correctly initialized `movesArray` and `namesArray`. Your code `namesArray[i] = parts[0];` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `namesArray` is null. Based on your comment you've only declared it as global variable using `private int[] movesArray; private String[] namesArray;`.

An example of an array declaration is:

```
int[] movesArray = new int[10] // 10 is the length of the array, as example
```

You can use [Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) if you're not sure what the size of the array should be.

Declare globally:

```
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and in your code:

```
namesList.add(parts[0]);
```

Comment: aah, is there a way I can do it without having to declare the size as the size of text file will change

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: works. Thanks @Mark